# Count string occurrences in string

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, count

I've been tasked with trying to get the occurrences of a string from a string. This is in the form of school reports given as a comma separated string. There's three different strings, Green, Amber, Red. I have to count these and output them as a report (of type string) like:

```
Green: 1
Amber: 1
Red: 1
```

As you can tell from the above they have to have a new line after each one.

I've written test cases for these and after I hard coded the right answers I haven't had any luck with trying to split the string in an array and try to iterate over them to count the occurrences of the Green, Amber, Red.

This is what I had before I started to experiment:

```
function report(str) {
  const arr = str.split(',');
  arr.forEach (el => {
    if (el === "Green") {
      return 
    } else if (el === "Amber" ) {
      return 
    } else {
      return 
    }
  });
}
```

This is what I coded. But it comes back as undefined:

```
function report(str) {
  let countGreen = 0;
  let countAmber = 0;
  let countRed = 0;

  let reportCount = `Green: ${countGreen}\n Amber: ${countAmber}\n Red: ${countRed}`

  const arr = str.split(",")

  // looping through the items
  arr.forEach ((str) => {

      // check if the character is at that position
      if (str === "Green") {
        countGreen += 1;
      } else if (str === "Amber") {
        countAmber += 1;
      } else {
        countRed += 1
      }
    });
    return reportCount;
}

module.exports = report;
```

Here are the tests:

```
const report = require('../src/report')

describe('#Report', () => {
  test('Returns a string as an output', () => {
    expect(typeof report("Green")).toBe("string")
  })

  describe('can count number of colours', () => {
    describe('greens', () => {
      test('counts one green', () => {
        expect(report("Green")).toBe("Green: 1")
      })
      test('counts two greens', () => {
        expect(report("Green, Green")).toBe("Green: 2")
      })
    })
    describe('ambers', () => {
      test('counts one amber', () => {
        expect(report("Amber")).toBe("Amber: 1")
      })
    })
    describe('reds', () => {
      test('counts one red', () => {
        expect(report("Red")).toBe("Red: 1")
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You're building the `reportCount` string too soon. You should do this when the counts are ready.

Comment: Thanks trincot, when should I be placing it then?

Comment: Just before your `return`... As I said, when the counts are ready.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Could you post an answer to this with the corrected code please? Been stuck on this for two days!

Comment: Sorry, but you should do an effort here. It is not difficult. Use a debugger and step through your code and see how the counts accumulate. Then before returning, set the string you are supposed to return with the now ready counts. The fact that you were able to write a template literal, indicates that you understand JavaScript syntax quite well. So go on... If however, you just copied code from somewhere else without understanding, then please take a step back, because that is not the way you are going to learn this.

Comment: I appreciate what you say. It's difficult when you're stuck on a problem and have tried to Google different ways to find a solution but you don't find any and have to come on stackoverflow and hope someone will help. That's where I'm at. I used JS maybe 7/8 months ago and only getting back into it now. I don't know why my issue is still persisting. I've tried different ways of writing my code but this way is the only way that I don't get 'undefined' as an output. I really am stuck and don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: I understand what you meant now trincot, I had to move the let reportCount after the forEach and before the return, I just don't know why the code isn't behaving like how I want it to and what changes I need to make to it so it does.

Comment: That's the art of programming, and it needs to be learned... through study and practice. The computer does exactly what you tell it to do in the program. If it doesn't do what you want, then your program is not reflecting what you want. For instance, you have `\n` in there, but the tests show that this `\n` is not (always?) expected. Your code produces a string that always includes all three colors, yet the tests show that this is not desired. It is quite evident...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these issues:

- You build the `reportCount` string before the counts have been done, so it will have only 0 as counts. This should happen near the end of your function, when the loop has done its work, and you have the counts.
- The tests show that when a color is not included in the input string, it should not be in the report either. But your string will always report on three colors. You need to check for which colors you have a non-zero count, and only include those colors. That logic is currently missing in your code.
- Your `reportCount` string adds a space after every line break. This is not what the description said you should do. The only spaces in the output should occur after the colon (`:`), nowhere else.

Not a problem, but:

- There is code repetition, i.e. your code is doing somewhat the same thing three times, once for every color. You can avoid this, by storing the counters as property values of a pain object that is keyed by the names of the colors.

Here is a correction of your code:

```js
function report(str) {
    // Use an object to avoid code repetition in each if statement
    const counts = {
        Green: 0,
        Amber: 0,
        Red: 0,
    };

    for (const color of str.split(",")) {
        counts[color.trim()]++; // Counting is easy now...
    }
    
    return Object.entries(counts) // Get each color with its count
        .filter(([color, count]) => count) // Filter out zero-counts
        .map(([color, count]) => `${color}: ${count}`) // format as string
        .join("\n");  // join with line breaks
}

/// Some tests:
console.log(report("Green"));
console.log(report("Green, Green"));
console.log(report("Amber"));
console.log(report("Red"));
console.log(report("Red, Green, Red, Amber, Red, Green"));
```

If you want to still do this with `if` statements and without any of the array methods, it could look like this:

```js
function report(str) {
    let countGreen = 0;
    let countAmber = 0;
    let countRed = 0;

    for (let color of str.split(",")) {
        color = color.trim(); // Do it only once
        if (color === "Green") {
            countGreen++;
        } else if (color === "Amber") {
            countAmber++;
        } else {
            countRed++;
        }
    }

    let reportCount = ""; // Start buiding...
    if (countGreen) {
        reportCount += "Green: " + countGreen + "\n";
    }
    if (countAmber) {
        reportCount += "Amber: " + countAmber + "\n";
    }
    if (countRed) {
        reportCount += "Red: " + countRed + "\n";
    }
    return reportCount.trim(); // trim to remove final line break character
}

/// Some tests:
console.log(report("Green"));
console.log(report("Green, Green"));
console.log(report("Amber"));
console.log(report("Red"));
console.log(report("Red, Green, Red, Amber, Red, Green"));
```

Comment: This is unbelievable! I have no idea how I could have done the for loop and the other return you put, they're very new to me. The tests I done were one by one as I was trying to replicate an external code review. I have just one test failing now which is the first one (and very bad) but the others pass with your solution! If it helps, I was trying to do something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxEuIUhn8RE but the person stopped short of showing how they would use BDD to make the code work for the report colours. thanks for your help trincot, I'll just go and examine your code

Comment: Thank you for helping trincot, just amended my first test to expect(typeof report("Green")).toBe("string") and all tests are working now. If I wanted to still use an if statement, how would I be able to do so? I wanted to build on the (minuscule) knowledge I have of JS and try do it in the way I was trying to originally.

Comment: BTW I don't have the rep points to up vote your answer but I'm sure if anyone else sees it they will!

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! I fully understand the second answer with the if statement

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. You are creating a reportCount at the begginning of the function. All values are at zero, so even if you found one, it will always show zero unless you define your answer after the count of each color.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. The only thing which @trinkot trying to say is that construct the final string with the counts after the `forEach` statement and just before the return statement.

Demo **:**

```js
const inputStr = 'Green,Amber,Amber,Green,Red,Amber,Green,Red,Red,Green,Amber,Amber,Red,Red,Green,Green';

function report(str) {
  let countGreen = 0;
  let countAmber = 0;
  let countRed = 0;
  
  const arr = str.split(",")

  // looping through the items
  arr.forEach ((str) => {
    // check if the character is at that position
    if (str.trim() === "Green") {
      countGreen += 1;
    } else if (str.trim() === "Amber") {
      countAmber += 1;
    } else {
      countRed += 1
    }
  });

  let reportCount = `Green: ${countGreen}\n Amber: ${countAmber}\n Red: ${countRed}`

  return reportCount;
}

console.log(report(inputStr));
```

More optimal/compact solution by using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method **:**

```js
const inputStr = 'Green,Amber,Amber,Green,Red,Amber,Green,Red,Red,Green,Amber,Amber,Red,Red,Green,Green';

const arr = inputStr.split(",")
let output = ''

var countsObj = arr.reduce((colorCountObj, currentColor) => {
   colorCountObj[currentColor.trim()] = colorCountObj[currentColor.trim()] + 1 || 1
   return colorCountObj;
}, {});

Object.entries(countsObj).forEach(entry => {
  output += `${entry.join(': ')}\n`
})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help Rohit. Thanks for taking the time to do this! 
Unfortunately when I run npm test, the outputs I get aren't the ones I'm expecting from my test suites and I now know it's because for the first test I only want to get "Green: 1" but it shows all the report colours with the number of occurrences. How can I change this so only the ones that show up (e.g. "Green, Green" and expect output to be "Green: 2") to come up as the end result? Sorry for seeming like such a beginner, because I am!

Comment: @Farzan Looks like you have to trim your array elements after split as " Green" will return false. Can you try this `if (str.trim() === "Green")` instead of `if (str === "Green")`

Comment: Thanks for that Rohit, I tried it but it's still the same. If it helps, the output is this when I do npm test: 
`- Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 3

    - Amber: 1
    + Green: 0
    +  Amber: 1
    +  Red: 0`
I know now I need to stop the code showing all three when they aren't found, but how can I do so?

Comment: @Farzan First just put the test cases aside and Confirm that if your code is working fine as per expectation or not as per the test cases examples you have ? If you code works fine then test cases should also pass without fail

Comment: That's what I mean, it isn't working like how I expect it to. I want my code to do the following:
1. Get the reports and extract the "Green", "Amber", "Red" that are there by splitting the string at the comma ","
2. Let me know how many of each there are
3. Return the amount of them as they appear e.g. report("Green, Green") should output "Green: 2" <= just like that (with the colon between the report colour and number)
4. The code then shouldn't output/return all of the report colours like how I'm getting now (I know it's because I return the reportCount but I don't know how else to do)

Comment: @Farzan this is how it is working right as per the demo I added in my answer. Or there is some gap in that ?

Comment: No it's not working like this. At the moment it is returning all three reports like so:
`Green: 0\n Amber: 1\n Red: 0`. I just want it to return the report colours it finds with the number of times they're found! I know it is a lot simpler than I think!

Comment: @Farzan But if you will run my code snippet it is working fine. You can see the output in the console.

Comment: So I tried incorporating your answer now and it comes back with the output as undefined:
`function report(str) {

  const arr = str.split(",")
  
  let output = ''

  var countsObj = arr.reduce((colorCountObj, currentColor) => {
    colorCountObj[currentColor.trim()] = colorCountObj[currentColor.trim()] + 1 || 1
    return colorCountObj;
  }, {});

  Object.entries(countsObj).forEach(entry => {
    output += `${entry.join(': ')}\n`
  })
}`

Comment: @Farzan Can you please share what input you are passing in your `report` method.

Comment: I'm just making it a function with a place for a string to be the input. In the tests I didn't mock or make a double for this. It's just report(str) that's it

Comment: @Farzan Sorry farzan, I am not able to understand what you are trying to say. I might not help further on this.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for taking the time out to go through it with me. The answer trincot posted really helped. Your answer was good if I knew what string I wanted to pass into the method

Comment: @Farzan He also posted the answer with same input string which i used. But yeah, Its fine. The main motive here is that you should get help on this problem statement.